# Installing python modules for a specific Python version on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I am having both python 2.7.6 and python 2.7.9 on my Ubuntu 14.04. My default python should be python 2.7.9. So I made an alias to it in my .bashrc

```
alias python="/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin/python"

$python -V
Python 2.7.9

$which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/X11/pip
```

How can I install various python modules for specific python version (2.7.9 instead of 2.7.6).

```
$python pip install paramiko
/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin/python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$python /usr/bin/pip install xlwt
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

How can I use pip and install python packages for python 2.7.9? I tried googling but could't find a way to fix my issues.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip ...` ? 
Context for `-m`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/
Anyway, it sounds like you might want to look into [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) :)

Comment: You haven't installed `pip` for Python 2.7.9. Install that first for this Python.

Comment: @Evert How to install pip for a specific version of python? Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Also doesn't python 2.7.9 already come with pip?

Comment: If python 2.7.9 was installed with pip, you should be able to run `python -m pip --version`. But the error message suggests that the pip module for 2.7.9 was not installed.

Comment: As for installing pip, use [the manual](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py).

Comment: Actually, the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ensurepip.html) suggests 2.7.9 was the first 2.7 release to include the `ensurepip` module. So before you install pip from its own website, first try `python -m ensurepip` and see if that works. Then in future use, do as sxn already suggested: `python -m pip <command> ...`. Be aware that the pip that came with 2.7.9 may be somewhat outdated, and you may end up having to install pip from its website anyway.

Comment: Alternatively, since you apparently installed 2.7.9 yourself, consider installing the more recent 2.7.13.

Comment: Two further notes: 1/ `/usr/local/lib` is a really awkward path to install things in. Consider simply `/usr/local` or `/usr/local/python2.7.x` a next time. (`/usr/local/` is the default for self-installed software.) 2/ I wouldn't alias things to `python`, since you may end up confusing system tools that use 2.7.6 (the difference is so minor it'll hardly matter, but just in case). Just alias it to e.g. `py` or `mypy` and run scripts explicitly with `py somescript.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, you can specified pip's path:

`$/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/bin/pip install paramiko`

It should work!